# Executing function embedded SELECT sql query to increase performance

Tags: oracle, plsql, hash, dynamic-sql

I have the following SQL query that will return the name of a column in a specific table. Let's say it return 'USER_PK' as column name when it runs.

**the query:**

```
SELECT max(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE OWNER= 'DW_01' 
   AND table_name='D_O_USERS' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME<>'USER_PK';
```

Now I would like to run the above query as part of a function but instead of running it and storing the value it returns in a variable (using `INTO` or attribution like initial_sql: = '...', followed by exec ) I would need to have it run inside one line of code as below (see part in bold)... So far I have been unsuccessful as it is interpreted as a string when using quotes ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function DW_01.EXECUTE_AUTO (db_schema IN VARCHAR2, db_table IN VARCHAR2, pk_name IN VARCHAR2, id_pk IN INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR2

IS

result VARCHAR2(4000);

begin

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select STANDARD_HASH( '|| **SELECT max(  COLUMN_NAME) FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE OWNER='' || db_schema || '' AND table_name=''||db_table ||'' AND COLUMN_NAME<>'' ||pk_name ||'**  ,''SHA512'' ) from '||db_table||' where '|| pk_name ||'='||id_pk into RESULT ;

return result;

end;
```

Many thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to amend you r code like below -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function DW_01.EXECUTE_AUTO (db_schema IN VARCHAR2,
                                               db_table IN VARCHAR2,
                                               pk_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                               id_pk IN INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
result VARCHAR2(4000);
begin

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select STANDARD_HASH( ' || pk_name || ',256 ) 
                   from '||db_table||' where '|| pk_name ||'='||id_pk into RESULT;

return result;
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi Ankit! Thanks for the answer but I do not think it is returnign the right result..

Comment: Hi Ankit! Thanks for the answer but I do not think it is returning the right result... What I look for is that the code will execute the equivalent of 'select STANDARD_HASH( USER_PK, '256') from D_O_USERS where USER_PK_ID=1  ' and NOT the equivalent of 'select STANDARD_HASH('SELECT max ( COLUMN NAME) FROM ALL ALL_TAB_COLUMNS  WHERE OWNER=DW_01 AND table_name='D_O_USERS' and COLUMN_NAME<>'USER_PK'.'SHA512') from from D_O_USERS where USER_PK_ID=1 .  To summarize I need the standard hash function to process the content of the column USER_PK and not the string USER_PK ...Hash key will be different

Comment: @ValeriuGiurca, Please try now.

Comment: Dear Ankit, indeed your answer solved my issue but in a somewhat unexpected manner: I decided to send the string containing the column name as a parameter so that has considerably sped up the operation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few ways to run dynamic SQL in SQL, and they're neither pretty nor fast. The function below uses DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML to dynamically run a SQL statement.

```
create or replace function execute_auto(db_schema in varchar2, db_table in varchar2, pk_name in varchar2, id_pk in integer) return varchar2
is
    v_column_name varchar2(128);
    v_result varchar2(4000);
begin
    select standard_hash(to_number(extractValue(xml_results, '/ROWSET/ROW/' || max_column)), 'SHA512') hash_value
    into v_result
    from
    (
        --Create a single XML file with the ROWIDs that match the condition.
        select max(column_name) max_column, xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml
        ('
            select '||max(column_name)||'
            from '||db_schema||'.'||db_table||'
            where id = '||id_pk
        )) xml_results
        from all_tab_columns
        where owner = db_schema
            and table_name = db_table
            and column_name <> pk_name
    );

    return v_result;
end;
/
```

For example, let's create this sample table with 100,000 rows:

```
--drop table test1;
create table test1(id number, a number, b number, constraint pk_test1 primary key(id));
insert into test1
select level, level, level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
```

This shows how to use the function;

```
select execute_auto(user, 'TEST1', 'ID', id) hash
from test1 where id = 1;

HASH
----
A36753F534728ED84A463ECB13750B8E920A7E4D90244258DE77D9800A0F3DAF8CBAD49602E960A2355933C689A23C30377CE10FC4B8E1F197739FF86C791022
```

In addition to problems with type conversion and SQL injection, the performance is terrible. Selecting all 100,000 rows this way takes 200 seconds on my machine.

```
select sum(length(execute_auto(user, 'TEST1', 'ID', id))) from test1;
```

Normally, running everything in a single SELECT statement is a good way to improve performance. But this extreme type of dynamic SQL will never run fast. You probably want to rethink your approach. Instead of trying to optimize the SQL inside a function that is run one-row-at-a-time, try to change the process to process once-per-table